# How to get the values of ion-checkboxes in ionic?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, ionic-framework

I have 4 checkboxes. How do i get the values of those that are checked? What should i type in my typescript folder? I am trying to get the values so that i can save it into firebase. Here is my .html code.

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Bedrooms</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="bedrooms" (ionChange)="updateBedrooms()"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Toilet</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="toilets" (ionChange)="updateToilets()">
</ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Living Room</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="livingroom" (ionChange)="updateLivingRoom()"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Kitchen</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="kitchen" (ionChange)="updateKitchen()">
</ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>

<button (click)="onLoadTasks()" ion-button block>Choose Tasks<ion-
 icon name="arrow-dropright"></ion-icon></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for the 4 ones

```
kitchen: boolean;

updateKitchen() {
  console.log('new state:' + this.kitchen);
}
```

Comment: It shows the change of state whenever i check and uncheck it. But how do i retrieve the data from there? Sorry i'm just a beginner..

Comment: store it into string array , `let list: string[] ; if(kitchen === true){list.push("kitchen")} if(...`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: let list: string[]] = Array();